# Unset all variables in PHP 7

Tags: variables, php-7, unset

I'm using the following script in PHP 5.5.9 to unset all variables, which works great

```
$vars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($vars); $i++) {
    unset($$vars[$i]);  //this is line 72
}
unset($vars,$i);
```

However, in PHP 7, they give the following messages:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /root/script.php on line 72
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Array in /root/script.php on line 72
```

My question is how to make the script work in PHP 7?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid those errors by using `foreach` instead of `for`.

```
$vars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
foreach ($vars as $var) {
    unset($$var);
}
unset($vars, $var);
```

The order of evaluation of `$$vars[$i]` is [different in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect). It's now strictly left to right.

Previously it would have first evaluated `$vars[$i]` and then formed a new variable from the result of that with `$`.

Now it first evaluates `$$vars` and then tries to find `[$i]` in the result of that.

Comment: Your code works. Thanks for the explanation, it is useful for me, since I just upgraded the server and didn't know about this. I have updated the php version in the question.